# Installing ubuntu 14.04 on ideapad u310

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, ideapad

I want to install ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo ideapad u310, the system that its currently on it is windows 7. I don't want to do dual boot but instead completely remove windows. The problem i have with this installation is when Im choosing to install ubuntu, connect to wifi and the step by which is hanging is installation type. The table with device/boot etc. is empty and when I try to add something, black screen appears and it stays like this.

You can tell by now that I know little about this, any help greatly appreciated!
[this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5761L.jpg)

The solution was just to create a new partition table in gparted

Comment: Can you write the solution as an answer and then mark it as accepted? :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an error with X or Drivers, My recommendation for easy results:

Download the new LTS Version 16.04 but do the server version; http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-i386.iso

Put the iso on a usb and boot to it to start the intaller, Do not connect to the internet, and just run the installer like normal.

Once completed boot up and run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Or whatever desktop you would like to run. I find the server installer to be simpler and less likely to fail :)

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work, I added a screen shot, there is no partition table and I cant change anything there. I just want to format my entire disc and install ubuntu from scratch